Extract user role using NextJS map from an array
I started studying NextJs a few weeks ago and I'm having difficulty extracting a value using map from a list where one of the items has multiple values to a specific key.
I am trying to create a RBAC menu. If the role have just one value, everything works fine. However, when I try to add multiple values I am not able to make it work.
My array:
export const links = [
  {
    name: 'TIMETRACKER',
    href: '/dashboard/timetracker',
    icon: ClockIcon,
    role: 'user',
  },
 {
    name: 'MANAGE',
    href: '#',
    icon: HomeIcon,
    role: ['manager', 'admin'],
},
 {
    name: 'SETTINGS',
    href: '#',
    icon: HomeIcon,
    role: ['user', 'manager', 'admin'],
},
]

The first one works as a charm, but the other ones just doesn't works.
My validation function is inside a map and try to validate every item of this map:
      {links?.map((link, indexItem) => {
        const LinkIcon = link.icon;
        return (
          <div key={indexItem} className="mt-2 md:mt-0">
            {!link.subitems && (link.role === userrole || link.role === '') ? (
              <ul>
                <li className="mr-2 inline-block md:mr-0 md:list-item">
                  <Link
                    key={link.name}
                    href={link.href}
                    className={clsx(
                      'flex h-[48px] grow items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-3 text-sm font-medium hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-blue-600 md:flex-none md:justify-start md:p-2 md:px-3',
                      { 'bg-sky-100 text-black': pathname === link.href },
                    )}
                  >
                    <LinkIcon className="w-6" />
                    <p className="hidden md:block">{link.name}</p>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            ) : null }
          </div>
        );
      })}

Any tip?
Should I create another Map to validate the permission instead?
Thanks.

you need to modify your link.role equality check to iterate over a list for the second and third configs.
e.g. instead of
            {!link.subitems && (link.role === userrole || link.role === '') ? (

change it to
            {!link.subitems && (Array.isArray(link.role)
    ? link.role.includes(userrole)
    : link.role === userrole || link.role === '') ? (


If this answer helped, please mark it as "accepted"
